# Can't programmatically set a ComboBox selection

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am unable to programmatically set the selection in a ComboBox.
I try setting various properties (SelectedItem, SelectedText, SelectedIndex) but the ComboBox does not display the Name. The first row of the ComboBox, which is blank, is selected. The return value of the setting of the Property is correct.
What am I doing wrong?

```
...
this.bsConstructionContractors.DataSource = typeof(Contractor);
...
public partial class EditContractorDialog : Form
{
    public EditContractorDialog(Contractor contractor)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.cmbEditContractorName.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue", projectView.bsProject, "ContractorId", true));
        // new BindingSource is important here, so as to use a separate CurrencyManager
        // because bsConstructionContractors is shared with another ComboBox on another form
        this.cmbEditContractorName.DataSource = new BindingSource(projectView.bsConstructionContractors, null);
        this.cmbEditContractorName.ValueMember = "ContractorId";
        this.cmbEditContractorName.DisplayMember = "Name";

         cmbEditContractorName.Enabled = true;
         cmbEditContractorName.Focus();

        // None of the following cause the ComboBox to display Contractor.Name
        // The first entry in the ComboBox, which is a blank, is displayed
        object myObject = cmbEditContractorName.SelectedItem = contractor; 
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("EditContractorDialog(): myObject: " + myObject.GetType()); // type is Contractor
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("EditContractorDialog(): myObject: " + myObject); // myObject is the contractor

        object myObject2 = cmbEditContractorName.SelectedText = contractor.Name;
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("EditContractorDialog(): myObject2: " + myObject2.GetType()); // type is String
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("EditContractorDialog(): myObject2: " + myObject2); // myObject2 is the contractor.Name

        object myObject3 = cmbEditContractorName.SelectedIndex = 3; // arbitrary index, just to see if it would be selected
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("EditContractorDialog(): myObject3: " + myObject3.GetType()); // type is Int32
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("EditContractorDialog(): myObject3: " + myObject3); // myObject3 = 3
     }
}

public partial class Contractor : System.IComparable
{
    protected int id;
    protected string name;
    protected string licenseNumber;
    protected Project project;

    public virtual int ContractorId
    {
        get { return this.id; }
        set { this.id = value; }
    }

    public virtual string Name
    {
        get { return this.name; }
        set { this.name = value; }
    }

    public virtual string LicenseNumber
    {
        get { return this.licenseNumber; }
        set
        { this.licenseNumber = value; }
    }

    public virtual int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is Contractor))
        {
            throw new System.InvalidCastException("This object is not of type Contractor");
        }
        return this.Name.CompareTo(((Contractor)obj).Name);
    }

}
```

Comment: go to `InitializeComponent` and paste section relevant  to `cmbEditContractorName` basically all lines concerting that variable.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I moved `.cmbEditContractorName.DataBindings....` throught `.cmbEditContractorName.Enabled ...' to the Designer, but this had no effect. (Though it think it is better that they are in the Designer, thanks)

Comment: Based on your settings, assigning a valid value to `SelectedValue` would be enough. Also it should be initially show the contractor of the project which you are editing in the form.

Comment: @AlLelopath you did not understand my comment. I want you to paste the designer configuration for that combo box into your question.

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood. Regardless, there are 2 answers below, both of which are valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SelectedIndex finding the index by contractor name:

```
cmbEditContractorName.SelectedIndex = cmbEditContractorName.FindString(contractor.Name);
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because you need to get an object reference to assign from the DataSource of the combobox itself.
Also for comboboxes I suggest you to use an `ObservableCollection<T>`.

```
cmbEditContractorName.DataSource = new ObservableCollection<Type>(your List<Type>);
cmbEditContractorName.SelectedItem = ((ObservableCollection<Type>)cmbEditContractorName.DataSource).FirstOrDefault(c=> c.yourProperty = "something"); // this will select the first item meeting your condition
```

Your code isn't working because you are assigning `SelectedItem` property with a **reference** of an object not existing in the combobox `DataSource`.